# How to echo error message from an check if duplicate email

Tags: php

I am able to search if an email is already been taken but I want to be able to echo the error message and put it somewhere else. Here is the code:

```
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '". $username ."'"); 

 if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {

       echo " $ERROR_MESSAGE ";

 }

 else {  

 \\ Rest of the code

 }
```

Basically the above php function checks if there already is an email in the database if there is already an email you can throw any error message. Here is the code:

```
        echo " That email is taken ";
```

If the email is not taken then it will let you continue. What I want to do is put a $ERROR_MESSAGE message instead and echo it somewhere else on the page.

```
 $ERROR_MESSAGE
```

How can I echo an error message somewhere else on the page?

Comment: I think you need to check for records that have a `COUNT(pk) > 1`

Comment: Stop using that old mysql php extension. It has been deprecated for years now!

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the value inside the check to a variable and then display it anywhere else on the page as you need to.

You can also put in a simple boolean to make checking things easier.

```
if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) 
{
    $ERROR_MESSAGE="That Email Address is already taken.<br>";
    $canContinue=false;
}
else 
{  
    \\ Rest of the code
}

// Code continues...

if($canContinue)
{
    // Do stuff here to continue adding the user account.
}
else
{
    echo $ERROR_MESSAGE;
}
```